# Unable to knit because the dudi.pca function from library (ade4)

Tags: r, knitr

It is not possible to knit to a document because the function dudi.pca asks for a parameter while running, once you give the parameter shows the result. But this makes impossible to knit to get a document.

Any idea how to handle these situations when working with functions like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example of your code? What if you use `scannf=F` and precise the number of axes with `nf`?

Comment: This article might address your needs of creating an interactive notebook
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html#creating_an_interactive_document

Answer (score 0):

As Lamia said in the comments, it works for me using `scannf=F`, for the same issue.

Thanks!